# Missing header dependencies with MinGW on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm trying to setup a cross-compiler from my Ubuntu laptop so that I can compile command line programs for Windows. I have compiled all libraries I need with g++ until now, so I wanted to do the same in order to produce the equivalent Windows binary.

I have installed gcc-mingw via apt-get, and it installed a number of binaries. I have compiled successfully an "Hello World" program for windows using the `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` binary.

However I have some problem during the compilation of my more complex project. I noticed that this binary includes different folders from the standard g++, and it can't find dependencies (for example, boost headers, bits/predefs.h, etc.). Is there a way to setup mingw parameters so that it works as g++ does out of the box?

Comment: There are no Boost headers because Boost isn't installed for it. There is no `bits/*` since those are for POSIX.

Comment: So what's the most correct way to approach this problem? For boost I guess I can simply pass him the installed folder I already have (as long as I'm not using compiled stuff), but for the rest?

Comment: For the rest, stick to the Windows API.

Comment: Problem is, I have not idea what predefs.h is. I did not #include that directly, and it's not included in any of the library headers I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The Boost library I was using was one I installed via apt-get. Apparently this meant that many `#if defined (__GLIBC__)` were automatically converted in `#if 1`. This caused the inclusion of some non-cross-platforming header files. Downloading the library from the website and using it solved the problem.